# generating 64 bit code on 32bit debian system

Tags: linux, gcc, cross-platform, cross-compiling, gcc4.7

Could you please describe that how have you installed **gcc-multilib** and **g++-multilib** on 32bit debian machine to generate 64 bit code?

I installed gcc-4.7.2 on my 32bit debian system(and also installed binutils-2.23). When i try to compile a simple hello world program with -m64 flag as

```
# gcc -m64 hello.c
```

I am getting following error message:

```
"hello.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in" .
```

Please tell me the steps to generate the 64bit code on 32bit debian system.

Answer (score 1):

You need to re-install gcc with this option in the `configure`.

Comment: I installed gcc-4.7.2 with configure  --enable-multilib and --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu And before this configuration for gcc i installed binutils with  --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu. And every thing worked fine. I installed gcc-4.7.2 successfuly though also i am not able generate 64bit code using -m64 flag on my 32bit debian machine.

Comment: # gcc -m64 hello.c
I am getting following error message:

"hello.c:1:0: sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in" .

Comment: @NIlesh can you update the question with the output of `gcc -v`?

Comment: # gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
COLLECT_GCC=gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/var/opt/crossgcc/bin/../libexec/gcc/i686-pc-linux-gnu/4.7.2/lto-wrapper
Target: i686-pc-linux-gnu
Configured with: ../gcc-4.7.2/configure --enable-multilib --enable-targets=i686-pc-linux-gnu,x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/opt/crossgcc --with-gmp=/opt/crossgcc --with-mpfr=/opt/crossgcc --with-mpc=/opt/crossgcc --with-system-zlib
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.7.2 (GCC)

Comment: The system is i686(cmd :uname -a), 32 bit debian machine(no lm flags in "flags:" in /proc/cpuinfo)